# How can I check in Laravel if the user is auth'd within the blade file?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an e-commerce site and when the user lands in I want a login pop-up modal to show.

The user will either need to be logged in or, if they continue as a guest, select the country they are from as the site only ships to certain countries.

I need this in an if statement because the modal should only show once when the user first loads in.

I know the logic should be something like this:

```
@if (< user is a guest > AND < no country selected >)
    // show login modal
@endif
```

But I don't know how to implement this in the Laravel Blade file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are prebuilt [`blade directive`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#authentication-directives) for this purpose

```html
@guest
 // this will run if he is a guest
@endguest

@auth
  // this will run if he login before
@endauth
```

but for your case you want a [`custom directive`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#custom-if-statements) that checks if a user is a guest and no country selected so you could create a custom one inside of `AppServiceProvider` you could add custom one in the `boot` method

```php
    Blade::if('directive_name', function ($value) {
        // write your logic here
        if(< user is a guest > AND < no country selected >)
           return true;
        return false
    });
```

after that, you could access it like this

```html
@directive_name
 // do something
@enddirective_name
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very help full as I didn't realise that you could create custom directives in Laravel!